# $wpdb variable is said to be null when i try using it

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do a custom login page with wordpress, but each time I try to execute queries (with `$wpdb`) with the database I get this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

I already tried using :

```
global $wpdb;
```

at different places in my code, and I tried using :

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php'
```

but it didn't change a thing.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

/* Template Name: Custom Login Page */

global $wpdb;

get_header();

if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        function sign_up_client(){
            // Sign up
            if(isset($_POST['emailUp']))
            {
              if(!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['emailUp']))
              {
                $clients = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_clients");
```

The only result I could get is the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: you also have to require the files that declares `$wpdb`, welcome to WordPress..  the place where code is a joke

Comment: it's either `/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php` or `/wp-load.php` - can't remember which one specifically

Comment: Ok i'll try this, thanks you.
Btw I was editing the post too, you've been too fast ^^.

Comment: You also need to check the scope  `global $wpdb;` will be needed inside the `function sign_up_client()`.

Comment: `!empty($_POST)` is not needed after `if($_POST)`, the latter also will throw a notice if it isn't set.